# closeDock method - using Enzyme Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Running the following test for closeDock. The test is passing at the moment but when I check its coverage, it does not change. using Jest and enzyme

```
 closeDock = () => {
 this.setState({ isVisible: false, tableMargin: 0 })
 }
```

Any reason ?
Test:

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><HomeTab {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>));    

 it ('Test closeDock method ',() => {
  wrapper.find('HomeTab').setState({
    isVisible: false,
    tableMargin: 0,
   });
 wrapper.update();
 expect(wrapper.instance().closeDock).toEqual()
 expect(wrapper.find('HomeTab').state('isVisible')).toBeFalsy();
 expect(wrapper.find('HomeTab').state('tableMargin')).toEqual(0);
});
```

part of my package json related to coverage

```
 "jest": {
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
],
 ],
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
],
"testMatch": [
  "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
  "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
],
```

Comment: share your package.json and your jestconfig files

Comment: the whole file ?

Comment: at least related to coverage

Comment: updated code - included part of package.json

Comment: what is the filename for your test?

Comment: index.test.js     class = hometab